# How Can I Use Variable in Azure Data Factory Pipeline Copy Data Task

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory where it got two job

1. Read from Synapse and write into file.
2. Write another file with no content

Both the file name should be same.

What I tried was creating a variable and use that variable as file name.

[image: Variable]

But I can't use that variable in Copy Data Sync Dataset.

[image]

How can I use that variable in multiple tasks?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT is correct. Here is a blog post I wrote last year with some more details: https://causewaysolutions.com/blog/creating-reusable-datasets-in-azure-data-factory-with-parameters/

Answer (score 2):

To pass the pipeline variable in the dataset, you need to create a dataset parameter first and pass the dataset parameter value from the pipeline.

1. Create dataset parameter.

[image]

2. Add the dataset parameter in the dataset where the pipeline variable needs to be passed.

[image]

3. Assing the pipeline variable to the dataset parameter under the properties.

[image]